# Why I am getting error in installing pyttxs3

Tags: python, cmd, pyttsx3

I am installing pyttxs3 but getting this error in command prompt
pip install pyttxs3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyttxs3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyttxs3

What should I do solve this?

Comment: Becuase it is `pyttsx3` and not `pyttxs3`. Try `pip install pyttsx3`

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in spelling of the package.

```
pip install pyttsx3 # Try this one
```